# Adding a PayPal button along with credit cards with exp-resso store

Tags: expresso-store, paypal

I have a checkout page with a drop down menu containing credit card options. The client would also like to add a PayPal button.

I'm using PayPal Pro as the payment processor. Previous iterations of the checkout page used PayPal express which provided the functionality we're looking for, i.e. Visitors click to go to client's PayPal page, log-in to PayPal, pay and re-direct to confirmation page.

I tried adding a button using PayPal's button generator, but it just caused the page to reload when clicking on it - it also disabled the "Place Order" button when I selected a credit card.

Any suggestions on adding a PayPal button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use PayPal's button generator, because that won't be integrated at all with Store. You want to add PayPal Express as an additional option in Store, alongside PayPal Pro.

You can enable both payment methods in the control panel. Then you will need to use either hidden fields or radio buttons to give users a choice of which payment method to use.

To do this, submit a `payment_method` field in your checkout:

```
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="PayPal_Pro" />
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="PayPal_Express" />
```